# Why is 'in danger' considered by most conventional dictionaries to be an idiom?

Tags: idioms

Merriam Webster defines an idiom as:

> an expression that cannot be understood from the meanings of its separate words but that has a separate meaning of its own<

It then goes on to categorise the phrase 'in danger' as an idiom. It literally means that someone or something is facing a danger of some sort.

I would imagine an idiom to be something more like 'a piece of cake' or 'spill the beans'.

Comment: Possibly because one is not in danger in the same way that one can be in a swimming pool or in a snowstorm.

Comment: In that case--wouldn't the prepositional phrase 'excited about' then also be considered an idiom since one wouldn't be happy about something in the same way that one can be about a birthday party or about a new film? @Jim

Comment: I didn’t quite follow that.

Comment: From your argument, it appears that 'in danger' is considered an idiom because elements outside of the phrase in question can influence how 'in danger' is interpreted. Might a simple prepositional phrase such as 'happy about' be considered as an idiom because its prepositional object can influence how 'happy about' is interpreted?

Comment: Note, it’s not my assertion. I’m only trying to come up with an explanation as why they might have said it.

Comment: I understand, thanks.

Comment: In danger, in extremis, in grief, in trouble.

Comment: “In condition,” meaning physically fit, is an idiom. I don’t see any reason why “in danger” would be considered an idiom.